# Is there support for OpenKODE core in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I was trying to port a library to Android
 and I noticed it uses
OpenKODE core and includes KD/kd.h.
 Is there support for OpenKODE core
in Android NDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what is present in the AOSP, there is no sign of the OpenKODE library.

**Edit :** Quoting from the [`android-ndk`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/CHV2W12R9I8) Google Group :

> Nope, there isn't. Most of KD/kd.h is a light wrapper around Posix
>   features though, so you should be able to write one.